# How to check selected video size using ELCImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, elcimagepickercontroller

I am using `ELCImagePickerController` for multiple video selection. But I want to get size of selected video. When user click on any video, then their video size is check.

Right now, all selected video information is getting in:

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
 for (NSDictionary *dict in info) {
   NSUrl *video url = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

NSLog(@"Video information is ::",url);
       }
}
```

I can find the video size in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method . But this method is called when user select all video. But I want to restrict user from selection of large size file.

I want to get video information when a user click on video ,If user click on one video then that video size is get and show a alert related to large size . 
Following is called when user tap on a video for selecting. But I am unable to get video information at this time .

ELCImagePickerController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldSelectAsset:(ELCAsset *)asset previousCount:(NSUInteger)previousCount
{
    BOOL shouldSelect = previousCount < self.maximumImagesCount;
    if (!shouldSelect) {
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Only %d Video please!", nil), self.maximumImagesCount];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"You can only upload %d Videos at a time.", nil), self.maximumImagesCount];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                    message:message
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                          otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Okay", nil), nil] show];
    }
    return shouldSelect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code Length:`

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:yourVideoUrl];

CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);`
```

Check the below code Size:

There are 1024 bytes in a kilobyte and 1024 kilobytes in a megabyte

```
NSData * movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourVideoUrl];

NSLog(@"%.2f",(float)movieData.length/1024.0f/1024.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment . But I want to get video information ,when user tap on a video not when all video is selected.Please see my question once again . I have made some modification for better understanding.